# createRoot(...): Target not is not a DOM element. Already tried solutions from similar problems to no success

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to get webpack to work with React 18. I've upgraded the syntax, and everything to be React 18. I've followed every conceivable solution found on Google to no success. Container is set right and positioned correctly.

Here's my Webpack config:

```
    const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ReactRefreshPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

module.exports = {
  mode: isDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production',
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
  },
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.jsx"),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /.yarn/],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        use: {
          loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
            plugins: [isDevelopment && require.resolve('react-refresh/babel')].filter(Boolean),
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
        ],
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /.yarn/],
      },
      {
        test: [/\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$/],
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        use: [
          { loader: 'html-loader' },
          { loader: 'file-loader' },
          { loader: 'ref-loader' },
        ],
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /.yarn/],
      },
      {
        test: /test\.js$/,
        use: 'mocha-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /.yarn/]
      }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      title: "Test",
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
    }),
    isDevelopment && new ReactRefreshPlugin(),
  ].filter(Boolean),
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

And my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <script type="application/javascript" src="/bundle.js" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppRoutes from './config/AppRoutes';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <AppRoutes />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Also here's my Babel config in case it is a factor.

```
module.exports = api => {
  api.cache.using(() => process.env.NODE_ENV);

   const presets = [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      ['@babel/preset-react', { development: !api.env('production'), runtime: 'automatic' }],
   ];

   const plugins = [
     '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
     'react-refresh/babel',
   ];

   return { presets, plugins };
};
```

Comment: Hi, do you have public repo available with this configuration? But what I can suggest is to change `loader: require.resolve('babel-loader')` to `loader: 'ts-loader'`, and options below to `transpileOnly: true`.

Comment: @m-s7 I do but it's private for now. I don't use ts for this, but would that work anyways??

Comment: Answered it myself lol. Nope, ts-loader won't work without typescript.

Comment: Without public repo I won't be able to help, but you can look at my repo: https://github.com/m-s7/react-core this is React18 with Webpack5 and TS, maybe you'll find something there